# Online accounts in Ubuntu 12.10 not connecting

Tags: 12.10, internet, empathy, online-accounts

I added my facebook and google accounts to Ubuntu online accounts recently but I keep getting the message "Connection to example@gmail.com failed No reason specified." Im not able to connect to any of my accounts using the Online accounts. But my pidgin account which dosent use the Online Accounts works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your specific problem is, it may be similar to mine or different.
I was able to fix my connection issues by removing all accounts (Ubuntu Online Accounts in Settings) , then signing out of all accounts (in all browsers) . After that I restarted the computer, and set everything up from scratch.
Then it worked again.

Hope this helps and will fix your problem.
If not, maybe someone else has a better suggestion.

Comment: I did try that but still dosen't work. Still get the message that "Connection to example@gmail.com/Connection to example@facebook.com.com failed No reason specified."